# How do I write an infinite loop that won't crash my browser?

Tags: javascript

How does one write an infinite loop in javascript that won't crash your browser. I have found two things on the internet regarding infinite loops in javascript...

```
for(;;){}
```

and...

```
while(true){}
```

the problem with both of these is that the crash my computer... I thought you were able to just put...

```
Loop;
```

at the end of the code and it would infinitely loop through the code, but I was wrong, what is the proper way to loop through code infinitely that will not crash my browser?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: `setInterval` .. ?

Comment: You can't.  An infinite loop in Javascript will always freeze up the browser because it will block the execution of any other Javascript, which is single-threaded.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: "*I have found two things on the internet regarding infinite loops in java*" - did you mean JavaScript? I'm assuming you did, but I didn't want to put words in your mouth by editing without confirmation.

Comment: yea... sorry. That's what I meant.

Comment: I was trying to find a way to have code repeat until you close your browser.

Comment: Google the second comment above

Comment: Or you can have a recursive function that calls itself after a `setTimeout`.

Comment: Yes, I have. I tried that, but it doesn't work. setInterval(code,timeInMiliSecs);

Comment: should work fine assuming the interval is long enough for all the code to complete and not overload the call stack... edit question with a [mcve] and you will get more help that way

Comment: I'm just trying to test it, but this is the code I have...   setInterval(document.write(Date()), 1000);

Comment: Okay, I've found the answer to my question...

Comment: <script>
setInterval(function() {document.close();document.write(Date());},1000);
</script>

Answer (score 4):

If you need to write some Javascript code that takes a long time (up to and including "forever") you should move it out of the main Javascript content and into a [WebWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

```
var myWorker = new Worker('worker.js');
```

This allows you to load the script in worker.js and execute it in a separate context that runs in parallel.

If you just need something to run once and while until the user exits the page (or closes the browser) then just use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers):

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(myCallback, 500);

function myCallback() {
  // Your code here
}
```